# Distributing a J2EE Application (Client-Server)

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, client-server, software-distribution

I have developed a J2EE project that is working on my IDE (NetBeans) but now I'm finding myself stuck as to how do I distribute the project. eg: to have my enterprise application server running on one machine and enterprise clients running on other machines.

I am using the Payara version of Glassfish Server since I needed to create connection pools for the MSSQL Server and my client program is an Enterprise application client.

I am still new to J2EE and would like my project to have multiple clients connecting to a single server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that this will help:

You need a machine somewhere and run Glassfish on it. What you should have is a `.war`-file somewhere since you built your project. This needs to be deployed on your Glassfish machine. Here is a tutorial how to do that [deploy war file](https://dzone.com/articles/how-deploy-war-file-using)